# Do not understand what's required when making cache

Tags: swift, xcode, caching

Implement a simple cache in your app:

Create a new file called Cache.swift.
Create a class called Cache. It should be generic with respect to the type it stores, and its keys. e.g. Cache.
The generic Key type will need to be constrained to conform to Hashable.
Create a private property that is a dictionary to be used to actually store the cached items. The type of the dictionary should be [Key : Value]. Make sure you initialize it with an empty dictionary.
Implement cache(value:, for:) to add items to the cache and value(for:) to return the associated value from the cache.
Add a cache proeprty to PhotosCollectionViewController. Its keys should be Ints as you'll use MarsPhotoReference ids for the keys. Its values should be Data objects, as you'll be caching image data. (You could also cache UIImages directly.)
In your PhotosCollectionViewController.loadImage(forCell:, forItemAt:) method, before starting a data task, first check to see if the cache already contains data for the given photo reference's id. If it exists, set the cell's image immediately without doing a network request.
In your network request completion handler, save the just-received image data to the cache so it is available later.

```
class Cache<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    private var storeCachedItems = [Key: Value]()


    //MARK: - Editing the set

}
```

I am very unsure of how to create this cache and I do not understand specifically #5.

Comment: Implement cache(value:, for:) to add items to the cache and value(for:) to return the associated value from the cache.

Comment: Ok that worked. Thank you!

Comment: Yes go ahead...

Comment: Hey I am also having some issues with the next step if you are still able to help out, Add a cache proeprty to PhotosCollectionViewController. Its keys should be Ints as you'll use MarsPhotoReference ids for the keys. Its values should be Data objects, as you'll be caching image data.

Comment: Some people think they can decide what questions can be answered or not. So they downvote it without a  specific reason. You can use the code I have posted without a problem. If you want to avoid such cases you need to add what you have tried and describe the issues you are facing.

Comment: Just add whatever you have tried to your post